# Bootstrap fixed sidebar example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Try the bootstrap dashboard example http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/

My interest is primarily in using their fixed sidebar template. But interestingly, the sidebar and its contents disappear when you switch to a smaller viewport (in case of desktop, smaller window screen).

Is it really hidden? or is there a way to view the sidebar even in mobile view?
(try the toggle device button in Chrome's debug mode for mobile view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is by design, they hide the sidebar for mobile devices or when the screen size is very small, in order to give importance to the content. If you wanna do something that doesn't get affected like this, you can start from this:

```css
/* Start Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
/* End Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */
a {text-decoration: none;}

html, body {height: 100%;}
body {padding-top: 50px; padding-left: 75px;}
p {margin: 0 0 10px;}

header {background-color: #000; position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%; z-index: 2; left: 0;}
header h1 {line-height: 1; text-align: center; padding: 5px 0; font-weight: 1.5em;}
header h1 a {font-weight: normal; color: #fff;}

aside {position: fixed; left: 0; height: 100%; top: 30px; background-color: #99f; padding-top: 25px; z-index: 1; width: 70px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <h1><a href="">Heading</a></h1>
</header>
<aside>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</aside>
<p>Jason John Gesser (born May 31, 1979) is an American college football coach and former player, currently the quarterbacks coach for the Wyoming Cowboys of the Mountain West Conference.</p>
<p>He was previously the interim head coach, offensive coordinator, quarterbacks coach, and recruiting coordinator for the Idaho Vandals of the WAC. He played quarterback for Washington State Cougars of the Pac-10 under head coach Mike Price, and played in the 2003 Rose Bowl. As a professional, Gesser played for the Utah Blaze of the Arena Football League, the Calgary Stampeders of the Canadian Football League, and the Tennessee Titans of the National Football League. He was originally hired at Idaho as running backs coach in June 2011. Gesser is the grandson of Green Bay Packers Hall of Fame member Joseph "Red" Dunn.</p>
<p>Jason John Gesser (born May 31, 1979) is an American college football coach and former player, currently the quarterbacks coach for the Wyoming Cowboys of the Mountain West Conference.</p>
<p>He was previously the interim head coach, offensive coordinator, quarterbacks coach, and recruiting coordinator for the Idaho Vandals of the WAC. He played quarterback for Washington State Cougars of the Pac-10 under head coach Mike Price, and played in the 2003 Rose Bowl. As a professional, Gesser played for the Utah Blaze of the Arena Football League, the Calgary Stampeders of the Canadian Football League, and the Tennessee Titans of the National Football League. He was originally hired at Idaho as running backs coach in June 2011. Gesser is the grandson of Green Bay Packers Hall of Fame member Joseph "Red" Dunn.</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes the default style is hidden. Line 33 in dashboard.css.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Anuj, It is hidden. 
If you open dashboard.css and go to line no. 33 you will find below code:

```
.sidebar {
  display: none;
}
```

if you change that code from `display:none` to `display:block` You will see side bar above your container division.

But you really want that fix side bar in small devices like tablet or mobile (which I dont recommend you to do), You will have to play with CSS and find a fix yourself. Here's something I did

```
.sidebar{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left:
}
```

I am uploading snapshot of both scenario.
[image: This is with display:block]
[image: Custom fix with scenario 2]
Thanks,
Jimish

Comment: Thanks Jimish! The 2nd option was what I had in mind, but there's that problem with small screens. Now, I am more inclined toward a sidebar like the one they provide at zurb foundation (animated, button-press-slide-out sidebar). Do u think that is possible with bootstrap?

Comment: Hey Anuj, everything is possible with bootstrap. I wrote sample code for you. Please download this zip file: http://jimish.5gbfree.com/demo/Desktop.zip

Comment: thanks a lot @jimish. its a lot of help and insight, seriously!
but unfortunately, i already i started my work with bootstrap sidebar (which tends to disappear on smaller screens). do you think the same thing you did above is possible with the sidebar?

Comment: Don't bother, @jimish. found someone who had already tweaked it.
http://bootply.com/128936

Answer (score 0):

this is the css responsive attribute @mediaquery by which you can apply the rules the elements on the specific screen size . i.e if you check

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.sidebar {
  /* other rules   */
  display: block;    //display on width more than 768px
 /* other rules   */
}
```

and for width smaller than 768px

```
.sidebar {
  display: none;  // it will hide the sidebar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You control by CSS only, using this code:

```
.navbar-fixed-top .sidebar {   display: inherit !important;}
```

Otherwise you create a parent id  set a css same fomat

```
#id-name .sidebar {   display: inherit !important;}
```